# Flutter: Update widget when childs property changes

Tags: flutter

I'm new to flutter. I can add some markers "over" an image, but would like to also move them around.

(see below for the complete code)
I've got `class _ImageWithMarkersState` which has a List of all added markers.
A marker has a `_moveMarker-method`. This method gets called, when I move the marker around!

Problem: The marker is not updated on the screen, unless I invoke a hot reload.
It seems that I somehow need to call `_ImageWithMarkersState`s build(). How is flutters framework for this?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(const MaterialApp(
  home: ImageWithMarkers(),
));

class ImageWithMarkers extends StatefulWidget {
  const ImageWithMarkers({super.key});

  @override
  State<ImageWithMarkers> createState() => _ImageWithMarkersState();
}

class _ImageWithMarkersState extends State<ImageWithMarkers> {
  List<Marker> markers = [];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Image with Markers'),
      ),
      body: Stack(
        children: [
          GestureDetector(
            onTapUp: (TapUpDetails details) {
                 _addMarker(details.localPosition);
                 },
            child: Image.asset('assets/summer.jpg'),
          ),
          Stack(
              children: markers,
              )
        ])
    );
  }

  void _addMarker(Offset position) {
    setState(() {
      if (markers.length < 4)
      {
        markers.add(Marker(position: position, size: 30.0, index: markers.length));
      }
    });
  }
}

class Marker extends StatelessWidget {
  Offset position;
  final double size;
  final int index;

  Marker({Key? key, required this.position, required this.size, required this.index}) : super(key: key);


  final List<Color> _colors = [Colors.black, Colors.white, Colors.red, Colors.blue];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Positioned(
      left: position.dx - size/2.0, // Adjust the marker position as needed
      top: position.dy - size/2.0,
      child: GestureDetector(
        onPanUpdate: (details) {
          _moveMarker(details.delta);
        },
        child: Icon(
          Icons.center_focus_strong,
          size: size,
          color: _colors[index],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  void _moveMarker(Offset delta) {
    //this works!
    position = position.translate(delta.dx, delta.dy);
    print("M$index: move");
    print("delta: $delta");
    print("updated position: $position");
  }
}
```

Comment: Take a look at Flutter docs: https://docs.flutter.dev/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/simple.

Comment: Thanks! This put me on the right path. I posted an answer/ solution below.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone that finds this question due to the confusion I had:

If you are from "traditional" programming, then you need to change your viewpoint when using flutter.
https://docs.flutter.dev/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/declarative:

> When the state of your app changes (for example, the user flips a switch in the settings screen), you change the state, and that triggers a redraw of the user interface. There is no imperative changing of the UI itself (like widget.setText)—you change the state, and the UI rebuilds from scratch.

and also
https://docs.flutter.dev/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/simple:

> In Flutter, it makes sense to keep the state above the widgets that use it.

Flutters doc about state management: https://docs.flutter.dev/data-and-backend/state-mgmt

My thinking was:
store the data within the object and let it draw itself (or trigger its drawing somehow). But since the data (in my case the markers) is the state of the app, it's stored "above". The (drawn) object is immutable; it gets destroyed and drawn again if the data changes -> it reflects the state of the app, but does itself not store the state.

Hope this helps some folks.